# java testing: accelerate time to test timeouts?

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4

I have an app that manages turns in a game, it's fairly complex and it has a lot of timers that generate timeouts.. since they interoperate a lot it's difficult to be sure everything's working right (and keeps working right).

I'd like to test it, but certain timeouts are of a few minutes, to test it completely it'd take at least one hour!!

Is there any way to fake an accelerated time for the timers? Or should I just scale all the timeouts proportionally down, test them, and scale them up again each time?

thanks!

Comment: Just a note: For such long running tests you might want to look into a Continuous Integration system such as Jenkins to run your tests in the background after each commit. That way you can run a small set of tests just for the changes you made on your desktop, and still fall back on your full set of tests for thorough testing with CI. You'll be notified when tests fail in CI, but won't have to run the full suit of tests yourself each and every time.

Comment: what happens when something times out & how do you detect it? the answer to your Q could be quite different if, for example, you say "it polls to see if timer has expired" or "a timer expires and generates an event that is passed to interested listeners"

Comment: timers generate visible consequences, no polling is needed by the tests, actually no timers are referenced in the tests..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do this would be to make your own interface that provides a thin wrapper around `Timer`. You then program towards the interface everywhere in your code. After that, you make two implementations of the interface. The first is the expected implementation that connects to a real `Timer` object like you have currently. The other is one that you can use for testing. In this implementation you mock the functionality of a `Timer`, but you have full control of how the events are triggered and how long they take. You could scale the duration as suggested by @aioobe or you could make a backing queue that could rapidly fire events so that there is no wasted time.

The point is that you don't have to make changes to the real code and use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to make changes needed for testing.

Comment: nice approach.. the mock timer should be places in the tests, right? So that it doesn't mess with the code..

Comment: Dependency injection is the ally of test driven development!

Comment: @luca: Correct. As an example, here is a basic sample using [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Motivation?tm=6#Dependency_Injection_with_Guice). You'll see how in the last code block, it knows the interface it is requesting, but the returned implementation depends on the model used to create the injector.

Answer (score 1):

There is to my knowledge no way to do a global scaling of the speed of the Java Timers. (Assuming they rely on the `System.currentTimeMillis` method, you could perhaps try to add your own bootclasspath and override this implementation with something different, but this is tricky business for sure (if it's even possible).)

I suggest you add a `TIME_SCALING` factor in front of periods and frequencies used for debugging purposes.

```
// ...
long period = (long) (someValue / TIME_SCALING);
// ...

// ...
double frequency = someValue * TIME_SCALING;
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

relying on timer ticks to happen on the right time is prone to difficult to trace and rare bugs

I'd suggest using locks, barriers, semaphores, ect. to guarantee happens-before relations on everything; this requires more interaction between classes but is more bullet proof (and allows the program to run faster in testing with only one timer needed if it goes way too fast)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just simulate the effects of a timer going off, and checking the state of the application based on that.  It wouldn't help test the timers, but it would be a way to test their effects.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a simple way.. not nice maybe but still.. I can do as aioobe said (the TIME_SCALING) put keep it private in the class, then access it from the tests using reflection.. this way at least it can't be seen or used by other classes..

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something along the same lines, but thinking about slowing down the JVM by messing with the internals of Hotspot. It's not that hard, but it can introduce subtle bugs if not done right. Anyway, I posted a question here asking something along those lines, and someone came up with the idea of running the virtual machine in VirtualBox, and slowing down the time (in my case, to gain extra CPU time). Perhaps you could speed up the time in your case, reducing CPU time, but making tests finish earlier. Or maybe there's a precision limit to the timer, or VirtualBox can only slow down time.. hmm.